# How to set jScrollPane trigger on a specific height?

Tags: javascript, scrollbar, jscrollpane, jquery-jscrollpane

I have a div with the style: `'height:auto;'` jScrollPane has triggered on the mentioned div (no scroll yet)
 
Suppose the contents of the div are increasing, so the div's height increases too and jScrollPane appears.

> Is there any way to force jScrollPane to begin scrolling when the height is greater than a specific size?
>
> jsfiddle: [jscrollpane on auto height div](http://jsfiddle.net/hpmhpm/6c9UT/13/)

after clicking on `Click ME` scrolls appear, But it's too soon. I want to scrolls appear when the height is greater than for example 400px;

Comment: Could you show us an example using JSBin or a Fiddler?

Comment: jsFiddle was added to the question.